# C++ Non-changing member variables with sub-class specific values

Tags: c++, polymorphism

My Class Hierarchy is thus: BaseClass (is an abstract class) then it has three subclasses that inherit from it: ArcaneWarrior, Guardian, Magi.

I want to have two non-changing values for DefaultHealth and DefaultMana that are specific to each subclass as they will all have different values for both variables.

I guess I'm just looking for the best/most efficient way to do this.

Should I just have two virtual functions in the base class to return DefaultHealth and DefaultMana, and in the subclasses hard code in the values I want?

I appreciate any insight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My vote goes to `const` values in the base class and a `protected` constructor:

```
class BaseClass{
  const unsigned default_health;
  const unsigned default_mana;

protected:
  BaseClass(unsigned def_hp, unsigned def_mp)
    : default_health(def_hp)
    , default_mana(def_mp)
  {
  }

public:
  // your functions...
};

class ArcaneWarrior
  : public BaseClass
{
public:
  ArcaneWarrior()
    : BaseClass(200, 50)
  {
  }

  // ...
};
```

This is superior to the `virtual` function approach in 2 ways:

- No virtual dispatch at runtime (no overhead)
- true `const`-ness (those values can't be changed, ever)

Virtual functions don't give you `const`-ness, see this example:

```
class BaseClass{
public:
  virtual unsigned GetDefaultHealth() const = 0;
  virtual unsigned GetDefaultMana() const = 0;
  // ...
};

class ArcaneWarrior
  : public BaseClass
{
  unsigned default_health, default_mana;

public:
  virtual unsigned GetDefaultHealth() const{
    return default_health;
  }

  virtual unsigned GetDefaultHealth() const{
    return default_mana;
  }

  void SetDefaults(unsigned health, unsigned mana){
    default_health = health;
    default_mana = mana;
  }
};
```

Comment: They only give you constness if you allow them to. Why should he add `SetDefaults` to the interface if wants them to be const. His current approach with a hard-coded value returned by a virtual function is also truely const (you cannot get more const than a literal). And if you don't like hard-coded values, you can still return the value of a static const variable of the sub-class/method/file. But I agree with the first advantage.

Comment: Dont the variables need to be `protected` too?

Comment: @Seth: They don't need to per se, only if you want the derived classes to actually access them. But in this case, it's only allowed because they are `const`. If they weren't, you'd be better off writing protected accessors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's really the best and most straightforward way to do it. With virtual functions, you get both the "non-changing"-ness you want, along with being able to determine that value through a pointer (or reference) to the base class without knowing the exact type.